# Function still working when statement is false

Tags: javascript

Im beginner. Im coding a simple text-adventure game. I want option.onclick work only if scenario == 0. It is supposed to give player basic equipment. But it works even if scenario variable is more than 0, and after clicking another option it gives player more equipment. Why?! In google chrome console it says that it is more than 0, so i don't really know what is happening now.

```js
let character = {
  hp: 100,
  equipment: ""
}

var scenario = 0;

let story = document.getElementById("story");
let option1 = document.getElementById("option1");
let option2 = document.getElementById("option2");
let option3 = document.getElementById("option3");
let stats = document.getElementById("stats");

stats.innerHTML = "HP: " + character.hp + "%" + "<br />" + "Equipment: " + character.equipment;
story.innerHTML = "Your name is Hirohashi Mitsuuchi. You work as mercenary. Goal of the game is to kill Ishiyama Tokiari, most powerful and richest of daimyo. You are now preparing to attack his castle. What are you gonna bring with you? ";
option1.innerHTML = "Take Katana and Shurikens";
option2.innerHTML = "Take Gun and Gunpowder";
option3.innerHTML = "Take Bow and Arrows";


function game() {

  if(scenario == 0) {

  option1.onclick = function() {
    scenario++;
    character.equipment += '[Katana] ';
    character.equipment += '[Shurikens]';
  }

  option2.onclick = function() {
    scenario++;
    character.equipment += '[Gun] ';
    character.equipment += '[Gunpowder] ';
  }

  option3.onclick = function() {
    scenario++;
    character.equipment += '[Bow] ';
    character.equipment += '[Arrows] ';
  }
}

  if(scenario == 1)
  {
    stats.innerHTML = "HP: " + character.hp + "%" + "<br />" + "Equipment: " + character.equipment;
    story.innerHTML = "After few minutes you founded a tavern. Unfornately you don't have any money so you can't afford a room. You decide to..";
    option1.innerHTML = "sdfasfsafsadas";
    option2.innerHTML = "sdafsafasfsa";
    option3.innerHTML = "sadfsafdsap";

    }


  if(scenario == 2)
  {
    stats.innerHTML = "HP: " + character.hp + "%" + "<br />" + "Equipment: " + character.equipment;
    story.innerHTML = "hgdgdfhdf";
    option1.innerHTML = "xcvbcxbcxbcxvbcx";
    option2.innerHTML = "ewrawafsadgas";
    option3.innerHTML = "nbcxnxbdsbds";
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(game);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(game);
```

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  line-height: 150%;
}

#container
{
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

#stats
{
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

#story
{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

button
{
  padding: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin: 3px;

  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <html lang="en">
 <title>The Twisting Moon</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" defer></script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="stats"></div>
  <div id="story"><p></p></div>
  <button id="option1"><p></p></button>
  <button id="option2"><p></p></button>
  <button id="option3"><p></p></button>
 </div>
  <script src="js/game.js" defer></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Your "click" handler functions do not go away by themselves when the "scenario" counter changes. They remain in effect.

Comment: How to make it work only one time?

Comment: Place the  if(scenario == 0) inside each onclick function, because the event handlers are called directly from the outside of your if.